# Smooth function $C^{\infty}$ that in the limit becomes Coulomb potential

Tags: limits, convergence-divergence, continuity, approximation-theory

I need to have a scalar function $\psi(\mathbf{r}, \sigma)$ of the coordinate $\mathbf{r}$ in euclidean 3-D space, which depends on a scalar adjustment parameter $\sigma$, such that in the limit $\sigma \to 0$ the $\psi$ function becomes the Coulomb potential of an electric charge on the origin,

$$\phi(\mathbf{r}) = \dfrac{C}{|\mathbf{r}|},$$

where $C$ is a constant that depends on the charge of the particle. So that

$$\lim_{|\mathbf{r}| \to \, 0} \psi{(\mathbf{r}, \sigma)} = \psi{(0, \sigma)}$$

for $\sigma > 0$, $\psi$ has derivatives of all orders everywhere, and

$$\lim_{\sigma \to \, 0} \psi{(\mathbf{r}, \sigma)} = \phi(\mathbf{r}).$$

That is, a function which shows Coulomb potential behaviour away from the origin, but is continuous at the origin, infinitely differentiable everywhere, and that can be made arbitrarily close to the Coulomb potential.

What are the smooth forms that have this property?

Comment: Lots of options exist. A simple case is $\psi(r,\sigma)=\begin{cases} \phi(r) & r>\sigma \\ \phi(\sigma) & r \leq \sigma \end{cases}$.

Comment: Yes, of course, I need to restate the problem.

Comment: $\phi(r) = C/(\vert r\vert + a), a > 0$.

Comment: @Aruralreader, thanks for the comment, but sorry I phrased it incorrectly. I have restated the question.

Comment: Still a lot of options, but harder to write them down explicitly. You may want to look up the notion of a mollifier.

Comment: @Ian, great, never heard of mollifiers before, and its very interesting. I found some works containing "Coulomb" and "mollifier" but none provide an explicit form. [This](https://static1.squarespace.com/static/5b1b6ab9e2ccd11f3d8b63fe/t/5f6a09e275de7e250122b0c2/1600784873304/GroMusSeiGor-JPCM-20.pdf) paper for instance uses a mollified version of the Coulomb interaction in 1-D. But then, reading the paper I found a very simple answer to my question: the *soft Coulomb interaction*, which has just the property I need. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 1):

While following the suggestions in the comments to my question, I found the *soft-core Coulomb interaction*:

$$\phi_{soft}(\mathbf{r},\sigma) = \dfrac{C}{(\mathbf{r}^2 + \sigma^2)^{1/2}}$$

which is obviously smooth everywhere and recovers the original Coulomb interaction in the limit $\sigma \to 0$.